# Failing to install scikits.sparse - Clang error

Tags: python, scikit-learn, installation, clang, sparse-matrix

I've been getting the following error with django:

```
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    No module named sparse
```

The importerror comes from:

```
from sklearn.svm.sparse import LinearSVC
from nltk.classify.scikitlearn import SklearnClassifier
```

To solve this I'm trying to install the sparse module for scikit-learn via the following:

```
sudo easy_install scikits.sparse
```

But I am getting this error:

```
no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/_build'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*~' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'scikits/sparse/cholmod.c'
clang: error: no input files
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
from sklearn.svm.sparse import LinearSVC
```

to

```
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
```

and forget about `scikits.sparse`, which has nothing to do with scikit-learn. The `sklearn.svm.sparse` module was removed from scikit-learn a few releases ago.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who was specifically interested in installing scikits.sparse. I was having trouble in Mac OS X 10.9. The problem has to do with setuptools making assumptions based on whether you have Cython and Pyrex installed.

A solution, and certainly not the best solution (that worked for me) was to install Pyrex. For macports users:

```
sudo port install py27-pyrex
```

Install SparseSuite.

Edit the setup.py file so that the value for the ext_modules is the following:

```
ext_modules = [
    Extension("scikits.sparse.cholmod",
              ["scikits/sparse/cholmod.pyx"],
              libraries=["cholmod"],
              include_dirs=[np.get_include(), "path/to/sparsesuite/include"],
              library_dirs=["path/to/sparsesuite/lib"]
              ),
    ]
```

For me the include and library directories for SparseSuite were *usr/local/include* and */usr/local/lib*.

Edit the following line in the *scikits/sparse/cholmod.pyx* file:

```
cdef extern from "sparsesuite/cholmod.h":
```

to

```
cdef extern from "cholmod.h":
```

Then try to install scikits.sparse again. Should work.